# gradle & maven-publish : what does "from"?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I have this line in a project ( I use the maven-publish plugin)

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifactId = jar.archiveBaseName
        }
    }
}
```

what the use of "from components.java" ?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:publications

Answer (score 0):

It indicates the component to be published, which in turns tells Gradle, amongst other things, which artifacts to publish.